# Internet Explorer compatibly stylesheet for WebKit?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, webkit

I am working on a WebKit based browser, but things don't render properly on a IE - only site. Does anyone know of a stylesheet I can inject into these pages to make WebKit render like IE6? Kind of like an anti [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

I know the proper solution is to make the site standards compliant, but it's not under my control.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to downgrade Webkit to make it work like IE6? Wow. That's a really really horrible thought.

Comment: Yup. The site owner isn't willing to put resources into supporting anything other than IE, so in order to support the site with my WebKit based browser I need a way to replicate IE bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good start would be to implement IE's Quirks Mode if no `!DOCTYPE` is specified. Aside from that you can also support the `X-UA-Compatible` header to see if the site is designed for a particular version of IE.

Aside from that, there isn't much you can do. It's up to the website owners to decide "hey, we actually want users to be able to use our site" and actually make it standards-compliant.

Comment: Thanks for the idea about activating Quirks Mode. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main things that make IE6 render so differently:

- Bugs
- Missing features
- Quirks mode

You will never be able to (nor should you want to) try to replicate IE6's bugs in newer browsers. IE6's bugs are legendary. You probably have hacks and work-arounds to deal with them anyway, but be glad that you're moving on and away from them.

IE's missing features shouldn't be a problem for you, because your code just won't be using them. Nothing to worry about. Obviously, it would be a problem the other way if you'd written a site for a newer browser, but not for you.

The main point of those three you want to worry about is the third one: Quirks mode is the one that really mangles page rendering in older versions of IE compared with other browsers.

The correct solution to this is to use a valid `<!DOCTYPE>` at the top of your page. IE will go into standards mode, and will render the same as all other browsers. If your page is designed for quirks mode, then you may have to fix it, but this is probably the right thing to do anyway, and at least the rendering mode will then be consistent between all browsers.

A good doctype to use is `!<DOCTYPE html>`.

If you don't specify a doctype, then you will have a lot of compatibility problems going forward.

There is one quick way out: There's a CSS feature called `box-sizing: border-box`. If you set this CSS property in your site, then Webkit and other browsers will switch to rendering the boxes the same as IE's quirks mode.

This sounds like an ideal solution and a direct answer to your question, so what's the catch? As always, the catch is IE. Trying to use `box-sizing` CSS without fixing the `<!DOCTYPE>` issue will still leave you with areas of incompatibility, and if you do fix the `<!DOCTYPE>`, then IE6 won't render in quirks mode at all. It ought to be the solution, but in fact, `box-sizing` will still leave you with problems to fix.

So I'll say again that the correct solution is to add a `<!DOCTYPE>`, fix your site and move forward, not try to pull other browsers backward.